# Output Post with ACF Fields into other Post

Tags: posts, custom-field, pages, import, embed

I got a post that should be embeded, included or outputted - however you call it - into another post.

I prefer a solo code variant.

So far I have tested various shortcode plugins - but they don't seem to catch the attached acf fields of my post.

The embedded post is a wall of several elements that should be attached now to other posts.

Is this possible in Wordpress? In Drupal you can easily load a node content (page content) into the template of another.

How to achieve this in WP?

Is there a way to import a **RENDERED** version of a post with all of its contents (also acf fields)?

Thanks?

Comment: If I understand correctly your question I would make a custom `_render_x_cpt_html.php` file and then include it in the `single.php` of the x custom post type, and also where you want to embed it, make a new `WP_Query` there, and afterward reset postdata.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Would that "_render_x_cpt_html.php" just be static html or a WP post entry? Could you show me an example? How is that _render_x_cpt_html.php file bound to an actual post element, that is changed via the backend?

Comment: I'll expand it in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To not duplicate code you could make a file in your theme/child-theme for the html of the post which you intend to embed, let's say `x_cpt_render_html.php`:

```
function get_x_cpt_html(){ ?>
<div class="x-cpt">
<h2> <?php the_title(); ?> </h2>
<div class="content"> <?php the_content(); ?></div>
<div class="custom"> <?php the_field('custom'); ?> </div>
</div><?php
}
```

Then you could embed this file in the `single.php` or wherever it's needed anyway for display for that particular custom post type:

```
get_template_part('x_cpt_render_html');
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
get_x_cpt_html();
endwhile;
```

Somewhat similar where you want to embed it:

```
$loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'that_post_type',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,);
get_template_part('x_cpt_render_html');
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
get_x_cpt_html();
endwhile;
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: Works. Very good answer. I do my query now in the template of an acf field element. So I am able to position the content exactly where I want it to sit. The field defines an reference to a post. This should be powerful enough. Thanks again.